# How to synchronize (specific) work-items based on data, in OpenCL?

Tags: opencl, gpgpu

### Context:

The need is to simulate a net of related discrete elements (complex electronic circuit). Thus each component receive input from several other components and output to several others.

The intended design is to have a `kernel`, with a configuration argument defining which component it shall represent. Each component of the circuit is represented by a work-item, and all the circuit will fit in a single work-group (or adequate splitting of the circuit will be done so each work-group can manage all the components as work-items).

### The problem:

Is it possible, and in case how? to have some work-items waiting for other work-items data?
A work-item generate an output to an array (at a data-driven position). Another work-item needs to wait for this to happens before to start making it processing.
The net has no loops, thus, it is not possible that a single work-item needs to run twice.

### Attempts:

In the following example, each component can have a maximum of one single input (to simplify) making the circuit a tree where the input to the circuit is the root, and the 3 outputs are leafs.

[image]

`inputIndex` modelize this tree, by indicating for each component which other component provide it input. The first component take itself as input but the kernel manage this case (for simplification).

`result` save the result of each component (voltage, intensity, etc.)

`inputModified` indicate if the given component already calculated his output.

```
// where the data come from (index in result)
constant int inputIndex[5]={0,0, 0, 2, 2};

kernel void update_component(
    local int *result, // each work-item result. 
    local int *inputModified // If all inputs are ready (one only for this example)
) {

    int id = get_local_id(0);
    int size = get_local_size(0);
    int barrierCount = 0;

    // inputModified is a boolean indicating if the input is ready
    inputModified[id]=(id!=0 ? 0 : 1);

    // make sure all input are false by default (except the first input).
    barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE); 


    // Wait until all inputs are ready (only one in this example)
    while( !inputModified[inputIndex[id]] && size > barrierCount++)
    {
        // If the input is not ready, wait for it
        barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);
    }

    // all inputs are ready, compute output
    if (id!=0) result[id] = result[inputIndex[id]]+1;
    else result[0]=42;

    // make sure any other work-item depending on this is unblocked
    inputModified[id]=1;

    // Even if finished, we needs to "barrier" for other working items.
    while (size > barrierCount++)
    {
        barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);
    }
}
```

This example has N barriers for N components, making it worse than a sequential solution.

Note: this is only the kernel, as the C++ minimal host is quite long. In case of need, I could find a way to add it.

### Question:

**Is it possible to efficiently, and by the kernel itself to have the different work-items waiting for their data to be provided by other work-items? Or what solution would be efficient?**

This problem is (for me) not trivial to explain and I am far from expert in OpenCL. Please, be patient and feel free to ask if anything is unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From documentation of barrier

https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/barrier.html

> *If barrier is inside a loop, all work-items must execute the barrier for each iteration of the loop before any are allowed to continue
>   execution beyond the barrier.*

But a while loop (containing a barrier) in the kernel has this condition:

```
inputModified[inputIndex[id]]
```

this can change its behavior with id of thread and lead to undefined behavior. Besides, another barrier before that

```
barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);
```

already synchronizes all work-items in the work-group so the while loop is redundant, even if it works.

Also the last barrier loop is redundant

```
while (size > barrierCount++)
{
    barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);
}
```

when kernel ends, it does synchronize all workitems.

If you are meant to send some message to out-of-workgroup workitems, then you can only use atomic variables. Even when using atomics, you should not assume any working/issuing order between any two workitems.

Your question

> how? to have some work-items waiting for other work-items data? A
>   work-item generate an output to an array (at a data-driven position).
>   Another work-item needs to wait for this to happens before to start
>   making it processing. The net has no loops, thus, it is not possible
>   that a single work-item needs to run twice.

can be answered with an OpenCL 2.x feature "dynamic parallelism" which lets a workitem spawn new workgroups/kernels inside kernel. It is much more efficient than waiting on a spin-wait loop and absolutely more hardware-independent than relying on number of in-flight threads a GPU supports (when GPU can't handle that many in-flight threads, any spin-wait will dead-lock, order of threads does not matter).

When you use barrier, you don't need to inform other threads about "inputModified". Data of result is already visible within workgroup.

If you can't use OpenCL v2.x, then you should process a tree using BFS:

- start 1 workitem for top node
- process it and prepare K outputs and push them into a queue
- end kernel
- start K workitems (each pop elements from queue)
- process them and prepare N outputs and push them into queue
- end kernel
- repeat until queue doesn't have any more elements

Number of kernel calls is equal to maximum depth of tree, not number of nodes.

If you need a quicker synchronization than "kernel launches", then use a single workgroup for whole tree, use barrier instead of kernel recalls. Or, process first few steps on CPU, have multiple sub-trees and send them to different OpenCL workgroups. Perhaps computing on CPU until there are N sub-trees where N=compute units of GPU could be better for workgroup-barrier based faster asynchronous computing of sub-trees.

There is also a barrierless, atomicless and single-kernel-call way for this. Start tree from bottom and go up.

Map all deepest level child nodes to workitems. Move each of them to the top while recording their path(node id, etc) within their private memory / some other fast memory. Then have them traverse back top-down through that recorded path, computing on the move, without any synchronizations nor even atomics. This is less work efficient than barrier/kernel-call versions but the lack of barrier and being on totally asynchronous paths should make it fast enough.

If tree has 10 depth, this means 10 node pointers to save, not so much for private registers. If tree depth is about 30 40 then use local memory with less threads in each workgroup; if it is even more, then allocate global memory.

But you may need to sort the workitems on their spatiality / tree's topology to make them work together faster with less branching.

This way looks simplest to me, so I suggest you to try this barrierless version first.

If you want only data-visibility per workitem instead of group or kernel, use fence: https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/mem_fence.html

Comment: `Dynamic parallelism` seems very convenient, even if at the moment I have no access to OpenCL 2.0 (I will look further if I can use it).  
Pre-processing the nodes in `layers` seems a convenient solution too.  I will probably use this one in the while of having access to 2.0.
Reading the last idea 'atomicless & barrierless..' I have the feeling you assume a tree-like shape, which in reality is just  for simplification of the example. In reality, it would have several paths to save, making difficult to calculate each stage in the way back.

Comment: Yes i assumed predictable tree path. Yes dynamic parallelism is very efficient since nothing waits for nothing and you spawn only necessary amount of gpu threads which adds more awesomeness. Have a good day.